# Управление этапом растеризации в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Вопрос сложный в объяснении... я работаю в связке C++ и OpenGL на windows в IDE Visual Studio. представим, у нас есть 3-х мерная сцена из 1-го полигона. Условно у нас есть "точки" растеризации, которые в итоге становятся после этапа растеризации фрагментами, для каждого фрагмента вызывается фрагментный шейдер и он в итоге заполняет текстуру цветом (или другой информацией).
[image: растеризация полигона]

А теперь другой пример. У меня тот же полигон, та же позиция камеры, тоже самое разрешение экрана (просто для примера я нарисую всего 14 выборок в случайных местах, это координаты пикселя первой верхней строки по x от 0 до 13 и так для всех текселей), но мне хочется самому задать каждой "точке" растеризации свою позицию, например используя просто текстуру значений с x и y, или какой-то простой математикой (растягивать сетку в 2 раза, как это можно сделать при помощи настройки ViewPort). Фрагменты останутся на месте, на своих текселях текстуры. Но вот растеризатор будет отправлять запрос функции фрагментного шейдера от другой позиции x и y, не упорядоченной равномерной сетки.
[image: растеризация хаотичных точек полигонов]

Вопрос в том, возможно ли достичь моей цели, или растеризатор в 3d конвейере OpenGL умеет работать исключительно только с сетками разных форм, в угоду оптимизации сложной 3d графики? Ну или ещё какая-то причина, почему это невозможно на OpenGL, или вообще на любом графическом API.

Comment: Не понял вопрос. *"Фрагменты останутся на месте"* Окей. *"растеризатор будет отправлять запрос функции фрагментного шейдера от другой позиции x и y"* Ну так вычислите эту новую позицию во фрагментном шейдере, и используйте ее как вам нужно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, этого я и боялся. что могу запутать. В данном случае позиция фрагмента, я имею в виду целочисленные координаты на текстуре в пикселях, если по детски совсем изъясняться. А позиция точки растеризации, уже другое, это место, откуда будет выброшен проецирующий луч, и вот если он найдёт полигон на своём пути, то вызовется функция фрагмента, туда передадутся данные о полигоне, соответственно можно вычислить глубину луча например.

Comment: т.е. если у нас обычно из центра фрагмента идёт "луч растеризации", и начальные позиции, откуда эти "лучи стартуют", образуют сетку, то я хочу чтобы у нас не было сетки, а сопоставлять позицию фрагмента с позицией запуска "луча растеризации" я мог самостоятельно.

Comment: *"имею в виду целочисленные координаты на текстуре в пикселях"* Это называется текстурные координаты. *"откуда будет выброшен проецирующий луч"* При обычном рисовании треугольников не проверяется пересечение никаких лучей с геометрией. Коордианты вершин треугольников переводятся из трехменых в экранные, потом на экране по ним рисуются обычные двумерные треугольники. А то, что вы хотите, называется [рейтрейсинг](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)).

Comment: HolyBlackCat, спасибо за комментарий. Смешно конечно, но то что я хочу: избавится от рейтрейсинга.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _"Коордианты вершин треугольников переводятся из трехменых в экранные, потом на экране по ним рисуются обычные двумерные треугольники."_ я думал, что на этапе рисования обычных треугольников я могу получить растеризацию в местах точек не только расположенных по сетке. У нас же на этом этапе "векторная графика".

Comment: Вроде понял, о чем вы. Похоже этого никак нельзя сделать. Да, растеризация не обязательно в местах, выровненных по сетке, но в каких имено местах выбрать нельзя.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это ответ на мой вопрос, спасибо ещё раз. Разве что ещё узнать причину, и зависит ли это от мною выбранного графического API?

Comment: Вот этого не знаю, пользовался только GL.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, однако сильно смахивает на проблему XY. ¿Чего вы на самом деле хотите добиться используя нестандартные правила растеризации? Если это что-то похожее на дизеринг, то никакие нестандартные правила растеризации не понадобятся. *"почему это невозможно на OpenGL"* - скорее это не нужно, а вообще эти правила обычно задаются на стороне аппаратной части.

Comment: @user7860670 я хотел следующее: смотрим на сцену и строим карту глубины (или сразу x y z фрагмента) в текстуру. Далее, мы смотрим от взгляда источника освещения, но растеризируем те точки, которые у нас были на первом этапе. В итоге мы получим позицию точек и их освещённость без рейтрейсинга. Это была идея для оптимизации воксельного (гибридного) движка.

Comment: @user7860670 мы можем для построения теней использовать карту глубины, и построить её с позиции источника света. Проверяем, доходит ли до нашего фрагмента луч, вычисляя глубину относительно источника. Всё было бы хорошо, если бы не качество такого подхода, тень получается рваной, или размытой. Но зачем нам сохранять все значения, которые мы прочитаем более одного раза, или вообще ни разу. Мы же знаем, какие точки нам нужно проверить, их позицию на сцене. И их предсказуемое кол-во.