# OpenGL задание глубины фрагмента для аппаратного отсечения

Tags: opengl, 3d

Как-то давно я писал вопрос про задание точек растеризации и терпел неудачу [Управление этапом растеризации в OpenGL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366837/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-opengl). Сейчас же появилась другая крутая и намного более достижимая идея.

Имеется некоторое кол-во полигонов в 3d, образующих квадраты, направленные нормалью к камере. Тест глубины сортирует каждый фрагмент и отбрасывает 100% не видные за непрозрачными объектами.

Вопрос в следующем: могу ли задать фрагментами их не действительную глубину, например, чтобы сделать из плоского полигона проекцию сферы (проекцию глубины)? Насколько знаю, глубина интерполируется между вершинами, но мне нужно не это.

Как я могу это сделать иначе: в данной статье рассмотрен кастомный алгоритм сортировки фрагментов по глубине https://habr.com/ru/post/224003/. Данный способ можно применить для сохранения полной информации о сцене в экранный буфер для последующей ручной растеризации, тем самым можно будет генерировать фигуры любой сложности, зная как вычислить глубину пересечения луча из камеры с фигурой относительно полигональной плоскости. Но данный вариант потребует включение ssbo и дополнительных этапов шейдинга, возможно я могу обойтись аппаратными средствами.

Планируется использовать это для отображения десятков тысяч объектов (простых и симетричных и не Ray Marching) с минимальным числом полигонов и высокой чёткостью, чтобы один объект мог пересекать другой.
[image]
UPD: для прояснения сделал 2d вариант иллюстрации. Красные точки, это центры окружностей, данные о них будут поступать в геометрический шейдер. Зелёные точки, это фактические вершины полигонов, направленные перпендикулярно к камере, генерируемые на этапе геометрического шейдера. В результате теста глубины должны остаться только фрагменты, выделенные синей линией на полигонах. [image]

Comment: Катастрофически не хватает иллюстрации того что вы делаете и чего хотите достичь.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что весь вопрос сводится к тому, можно ли заполнить буфер глубины собственными данными.

Comment: @Kromster, приношу извинения, у меня нет прототипа. Возможно, надо попробовать сделать иллюстрацию обычными графическими редакторами.

Comment: @user7860670, и да и нет. Если сделать это заранее, то мы просто отсечём плоские полигоны. Нужно, чтобы то, что вызывает функцию фрагментов, поняло, что их глубина не привязана к глубине полигона. Возможно, действительно нужно идти по пути запасного варианта с ручной сортировкой фрагментов после рендера сцены(

Comment: Это получается какой-то аналог сортировки от камеры в глубь для сокращения overdraw?

Comment: Если сделать это заранее, то можно задать каждому пикселю произвольную глубину.

Answer (score 1):

> Данный способ можно применить для сохранения полной информации о сцене в экранный буфер для последующей ручной растеризации, тем самым можно будет генерировать фигуры любой сложности, зная как вычислить глубину пересечения луча из камеры с фигурой относительно полигональной плоскости.

Не совсем ясно что вы планируете отправлять в буфер и как делать "ручную растеризацию". Но похоже, что ваша цель всё же не связывать вычисления в параметрами камеры (Position, DepthOfView или FocalLense), а получить объёмный рендеринг в зависимости от источников освещения и их перемещения. Для этого, например, в открытой графической платформе GLScene для C++/Delphi есть классный объект TGLShadowVolume. Вот иллюстрация его работы -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]